# How to make custom dashed border with radius in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have searched all over the internet to find how to create a custom dashed border with radius in react native.

This is what I am trying to achieve [image]

What I found best so far to work with what I need is a npm package called react-native-dash. 
This package allows you to create dashed lines separately for all 4 sides. but you cannot get them to curve at the ends and I do not like that.

```
<Dash dashGap={10} dashLength={10} dashThickness={1} dashColor={'#D8D8D8'} 
style={{width:'100%', height:'100%', borderRadius:30, flexDirection:'column'}}>
         <Text>Cake Marbella will go here</Text>
</Dash>
```

I am wondering if anyone has an idea about any other packages out there, or maybe how I could use borderImage in React Native ? (As I have read it is not supported, I tried using 'styled-components' library for it that would convert css to react native styles.

If anyone has any kind of tips of how I could implement it myself, I'd be glad to hear!

Comment: Maybe a SVG as background for the View ? If everything else fails. Or even better, there is a SVG library for react-native, you can use it to create a path for the dashes.

Comment: great suggestion! I will try that and let you know how it works out @CevaComic

Comment: So by "custom dashed border" I assume you've tried some simple CSS like `border: dashed 1px #d8d8d8; border-radius: 20px;` using the CSSinJS syntax OFC?

Comment: @DrewReese definitely, the problem is that I'd like dashes to be specific length with specific gaps between them, which CSS does not offer